# AngularJS limitTo split on special tag

Tags: c#, angularjs

I have a long text field and I want to create an expand/collapse method to show a short description and a long description.

Say I have a string looking this: `<p>Test 1</p><p>Test 2</p><p>Test 3</p><p>Test 4</p><p>Test 5</p><p>Test 6</p>`

How can I say that I only want the first 3 paragraphs so my short description output would be `<p>Test 1</p><p>Test 2</p><p>Test 3</p>` ?

In C# I did the following. Probably not the best solution but it works and it sends this to the view. However, can this be easier solved just in the angular view?

```
public string DescriptionShort
{
    get {
        return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Description) ? String.Join(String.Empty, Description.Split(new[] { "</p>" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Take(3).ToArray()) + "</p>" : "";
    }
    set { _DescriptionShort = value; }
}
```